# Is my Openwrt Router bricked?

Tags: networking

i m new on this forum and i have a (big) problem:
I think i bricked my router ( Sitecom WLR-8100 V1001 / X8 AC1750 )

I successfully installed OpenWrt 19.07.2 on it and it worked well, then i tried to install DD-Wrt on it (`dd-wrt.v23_generic.bin`) through the web interface (Luci). I got a warning message and I forced the update, my router should update and reboot and here i am.

Since yesterday noway to communicate with the router anymore: Web interface (Luci) / Putty / WinSCP.

How can i check it ? How can i fix it ?

Thank you very much in advance for your help and support and hope to hear from you very soon.

Best regards

Comment: what was the warning message?

Comment: i don t remember exactely, something like do you want to force the update, and i tiped yes...(

Comment: maybe the message warned you that you could brick the router unless you did something else first

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you did, and what state the router is in.

According to the OpenWRT page on the [WLR-8100](https://openwrt.org/toh/sitecom/wlr-8100), it uses uboot, so unless you've overwritten the bootloader in your installation attempts, you should be able to get load the original firmware image (you still have that, don't you?) onto it via [TFTP recovery](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/troubleshooting/tftpserver).

Comment: first thank you to answer me.

Comment: first thank you to answer me. i tried to be as clear as possible. i have the openwrt firmware yes. i tried the tftp recovery but it doesn t seem to be working. when i ping the router the light on router is blinking.